# Find minimal value $P=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$ if $ab+bc+ca=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}>0.$

Tags: inequality, examples-counterexamples, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

**Question.** Given non-negative real numbers $a,b,c$ satisfying $ab+bc+ca=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}>0.$ Find the minimal value of $P$ $$P=(a+b)(b+c)(c+a).$$

I check that Mininum is $8$ achieved at  $a=b=c=1$ or $a=0; b=c=\sqrt[3]{4}.$

I hope the following will help $$9(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\ge 8(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)=8(a+b+c)(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})$$
The rest is proving $(a+b+c)(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})\ge 9.$ I still don't know how to continue.

Hope you help me. Thank you.

Comment: One idea here is to let $x=\sqrt{a},y=\sqrt{b},z=\sqrt{c}$. This eliminates the square roots in favor of linear and quadratic expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality, which you got is wrong.

Try $(a,b,c)=\left(\sqrt[3]4,\sqrt[3]4,0\right).$

We need to prove that $$2\sqrt[3]4\cdot2\sqrt[6]4\geq9,$$ which is $8\geq9.$

My solution.

We need to prove that $$\prod_{cyc}(a^2+b^2)(a+b+c)^2\geq8(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)^2,$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are non-negatives.

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$((a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)-3a^2b^2c^2)(a+b+c)^2\geq8(a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2)^2$$ or

$$((9u^2-6v^2)(9v^4-6uw^3)-3w^6)\geq8(9v^4-6uw^3)^2$$ and we see that we need to prove that $f(w^3)\geq0,$ where $f$ is a concave function.

Thus, by $uvw$ it's enough to prove $f(w^3)\geq0$ for equality case of two variables.

For $b=c=0$ we obtain an equality and  $b=c=1$ gives
$$4(a^2+1)^2(a+2)^2\geq8(2a^2+1)^2$$ or
$$a(a-1)^2(a^3+6a^2+a+4)\geq0,$$ which ends the proof.